# Is there a way to locate celestial bodies indoors?

Tags: astronomy, celestial-mechanics

I mean, without being able to see the sky is there any analog way I can calculate where a planet/star/constellation is, and point in that direction?

I have found apps like Star Chart, which as an AR mode, so I can see from the screen if my phone is pointing toward the constellation or not.

But I want to know, without any electronics - what else can be used to accurately point toward a certain star - for example, with a compass, level, pen & paper, knowledge of the date & time, etc. What would be needed? If this is even possible to do without an app.

Answer (score 1):

The app isn't magic.  You could calculate the information (albeit much more slowly) by hand.  The things it has that you would need to replicate the information are:

- Ephemerides.  Tables of where objects will be located on the celestial sphere at a particular time.  These can be printed out ahead of time.  Or for stars, just a table of their (static) right ascension and declination.
- Your current location on the earth.  The phone can capture this with a GPS receiver or by SSID lookup from nearby wifi.  This can be easily found from a map.
- Your orientation with respect to the earth.  The phone does this with an accelerometer to detect the direction of gravity.  It will usually use a magnetometer to tell the direction of magnetic north, and then a table to convert that to geographic north.  For you, down/up is easy.  All you need is  north.  That can be approximated with a compass, or it may be known from how the structure was built.
- The current time.  The phone has this through either a GPS or a cellular broadcast message.  Presumably any clock will be sufficient for your precision.
- Astronomical algorithms.  The calculations to convert the right ascension and declination to azimuth and altitude are not particularly complex, but can be tedious to do by hand.
- Pointing device.  You need the angles from the horizon and from north.  You could make something with a protractor, or could use an altazimuth telescope mount with angles marked.

Comment: Re orientation with respect to North: A magnetic compass can be misleading in modern buildings as there are lots of metals and electric currents. Better is, as you suggest, find out how the house was built, or look at a local map. Assuming you're is not locked into a windowless building with no contact to the outside world, you can also just look out of the window at noon and get South/North from the sun, and record it. Of course this all needs preparation, so it's not useful when you suddenly wonder "where is Sirius right now?".

Answer (score 0):

You could download and print a stargazing planisphere appropriate to your latitude, or buy one for a few dollars. Then you just need the date and time, a compass, and your compass declination to get within a few degrees.